# Jquery Library Conflict - Overlay Not Working

Tags: jquery, conflict

Jquery conflict means my 2 pieces of functionality refuse to work together. I've tried switching the order of the scripts and replacing $ function to Jquery function. Doesn't seem to fix the problem!

```
  <div id="mainICONZ" class="iconz">
                <ul class="iconz">
                <li><img src="images/icon-1.png" rel="#mies1"></li>
                <li><img src="images/icon-2.png" rel="#mies2"></li>
                <li><img src="images/icon-3.png" rel="#mies3"></li>
                <li><img src="images/icon-4.png" rel="#mies4"></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

    <div class="simple_contact3" id="mies1">all over the content</div>
            <div class="simple_contact3" id="mies2">all over the content</div>
            <div class="simple_contact3" id="mies3">all over the content</div>
            <div class="simple_contact3" id="mies4">all over the content</div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> !-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
                  <!-- <script>
    // What is $(document).ready ? See: http://flowplayer.org/tools/using.html#document_ready
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {



    $("img[rel], a[rel]").overlay({expose: '#fff'});

    });
    </script> 
            <script type="text/javascript"> OTHER SCRIPT HERE!! </script>
```

Comment: What errors do you receive in the console? There's no need to use `$(document).ready()` there, as the DOM is already loaded.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined hoverIntent.js:112

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined superfish.js:126

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index3.html:25

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'overlay' index3.html:452

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'overlay'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
```

and then replace $ with  jQuery.

Comment: Like this? 

      `<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {



$("img[rel], a[rel]").overlay({expose: '#fff'});

});
</script>`  

Do I have to use it on both scripts? It doesn't seem to work, in this instance both scripts are broken!

Comment: You have to use Jquery instead of $ for all scripts.